# What is the difference between "normal" and "latin-9 only" keyboard layout?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

As you might know (actually not) for the [bépo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#B%C3%89PO) French keyboard variant on Linux there are two choices: French (Bepo, ergonomic, Dvorak way) **OR** French (Bepo, ergonomic, Dvorak way, *Latin-9 only*).
This can also be seen in the following screenshot: [image]

My question here would be: what is the difference between those two options? Is one better than the other? Is there any reason to use one over the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that "Latin-9" refers to the [ISO 8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) character set. That is, "Latin-9 only" is supposed to exclude symbols which require full Unicode support.

For example, the regular Bépo variant has `ə` (schwa) on <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>. This symbol does not exist in ISO 8859-15, and is therefore not included in the "Latin-9" variant.

You can open `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/fr` to see the definitions.

---

Or at least that's *supposed to be* the case. In practice it doesn't seem to work as intended.

Since `bepo_latin9` is based on `bepo` and simply *removes* characters instead of adding, it seems the overrides do not fully take effect and the extra symbols are *not* excluded – <kbd>Z</kbd> still has schwa on level 3 and level 4, and so on.

I used GNOME's "Show Keyboard Layout" button in the taskbar's keyboard menu – it displays the layouts as they're ultimately interpreted by libxkbcommon, and as you can see the differences are very minor.

```
gkbd-keyboard-display -l $'fr\tbepo'
```

[image: fr+bepo]

```
gkbd-keyboard-display -l $'fr\tbepo_latin9'
```

[image: fr+bepo_latin9]

<sub>Disregard the weird Caps Lock position – that's my local configuration.</sub>

---

So which one to use? Well, practically all systems can cope with Unicode nowadays, so just go with the regular `bepo` layout. Don't bother with `bepo_latin9`.